# How to write properties file in Java web application?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to write some values to properties file which is located in WEB-INF folder.
Following is my code-

```
Properties result = new Properties();     
result.setProperty(user, value);
result.store(new FileOutputStream(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/properties.props").trim()), null);
```

Whenever i run my code,there is no data in properties file.
It shows an empty file.

Please let me know how to write properties file in java web application.

Comment: Put your properties file in `WEB-INF/classes` and access it through `Class#getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: Is it possible to use getResourceAsStream for outputstream?

Comment: No. You shouldn't be writing to any file in your webapp context. Choose a directory outside the webapp and write there.

Comment: Also check the JavaDoc of the `Properties.store()` method. It does flush the stream, but it does not *close* the stream. So make sure you do that, else all bad stuff may happen :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Make up your mind. Which is it? Put it in WEB-INF/classes or outside the webapp?

Comment: @EJP I had not originally realized that OP wanted to write to the file. Imo, it should be outside.